# ld : file not found : warning, Error : clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, build

[image]
while running on device and making build getting above error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cool story bro! It's completely impossible to tell why you are getting a linker error from the tiny little screenshot you posted. You need to provide a lot more information about your project. Are you building for the sim, or a device? (It looks like you're building for the sim.) Do you have one or more third party libraries/frameworks you have included?

Comment: I hven't added any 3rd party libraries and just connecting with the device with out sim @DuncanC

Comment: From that tiny little screen-shot you posted, it looks like it's complaining about a library called libdyld. From a little google searching, it sounds like that's a Mac OS library. Take a look at the libraries and frameworks included in your project. Something is not right.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your BuildValidArchitecturesOnly in **Build settings** to NO.

Try adding arm7, arm64 (this is based on the type of device you are running your code) to your validArchitectures.

Try cleaning your setup.. Cmd+Shift+K

Delete Derived Data..

Use Valid developer certificate/Profile

Run & see..

Answer (score 0):

It means the library not support 64 bit, you need to remove arm64 from your build settings(`Project->build Settings->Architectures`) if you just want to compile successfully.

If you intend to submit app to apple store, better to modify your code to make it support for 64bit.

Comment: I have removed arm64 but still issue not solved